# How can I return false if more than one number while ignoring "0"'s?

Tags: python, sudoku

This is a function in a greater a program that solves a sudoku puzzle. At this point, I would like the function to return false if there is more then 1 occurrence of a number unless the number is zero. What do am I missing to achieve this?

L is a list of numbers

```
l =[1,0,0,2,3,0,0,8,0]  

def alldifferent1D(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if l.count(l[i])>1 and l[i] != 0:  #does this do it?
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have an example of what `l` is . Is it a row / column / box of the whole grid? Is it the whole grid?

Comment: Why are you iterating over the length of `l` when you only care about its contents?

Comment: It's an ugly way to do it. Is it not working? Do you have an example that fails?

Comment: Additionally, you seem to believe that your code fails under certain conditions. Could you give us an example of the condition where it fails to work properly?

Comment: l is a list of numbers , for example,  l =[1,0,0,3,6,0,0,]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the list is length 9, you can ignore the inefficiency of using `count` here (Using a helper datastructure - `Counter` etc probably takes longer than running `.count()` a few times). You can write the expression to say they are all different more naturally as:

```
def alldifferent1D(L):
    return all(L.count(x) <= 1 for x in L if x != 0)
```

This also saves calling `count()` for all the `0`'s

Comment: This is a lot simpler than my Counter version +1

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, you have to be careful with `filter` in python3 it doesn't return a list, so you can't consume it twice

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import counter
>>> def all_different(xs):
...     return len(set(Counter(filter(None, xs)).values()) - set([1])) == 0
```

Tests:

```
>>> all_different([])
True
>>> all_different([0,0,0])
True
>>> all_different([0,0,1,2,3])
True
>>> all_different([1])
True
>>> all_different([1,2])
True

>>> all_different([0,2,0,1,2,3])
False
>>> all_different([2,2])
False
>>> all_different([1,2,3,2,2,3])
False
```

Answer (score 0):

So we can break this down into two problems:

1. Getting rid of the zeros, since we don't care about them.
2. Checking if there are any duplicate numbers.

Striping the zeros is easy enough:

```
filter(lambda a: a != 0, x)
```

And we can check for differences in a `set` (which has only one of each element) and a `list`

```
if len(x) == len(set(x)):
    return True
return False
```

Making these into functions we have:

```
def remove_zeros(x):
    return filter(lambda a: a != 0, x)

def duplicates(x):
    if len(x) == len(set(x)):
        return True
    return False

def alldifferent1D(x):
    return duplicates(remove_zeros(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid searching for every entry in every position is to:

```
flags = (len(l)+1)*[False]; 
for cell in l:
    if cell>0:
        if flags[cell]:
          return False
       flags[cell] = True
return True
```

The `flags` list has a `True` at index k if the value k has been seen before in the list.

I'm sure you could speed this up with list comprehension and an all() or any() test, but this worked well enough for me.

PS: The first intro didn't survive my edit, but this is from a Sudoku solver I wrote years ago. (Python 2.4 or 2.5 iirc)